# is it possible/efficient to put fpu exception or inf into work?

Tags: c++, optimization, x86, sse, fpu

I got such code

loop 10 M:

```
 if( fz != 0.0)     
 { 
  fhx += hx/fz; 
 }
```

this is called 10 M times in loop needs to be very fast - I onlly need to catch the case when fz is not zero, not to make div by zero error, but it is a very rare case, 
indeed on 10M cases it should be zero, i dont know once , twice or newer

can i in some way get rid of this 10M of ifs and use "nan/inf" or maybe catching the exception and continue? (if fz is zero i need        fhx += 0.0, i mean nothing just continue 
? is it possible/efficient to put fpu exception or inf into work?

(Im using c++/mingw32)

Comment: You're really working with FPU code? With SSE you could easily compare and mask (instead of branch).

Comment: How predictable is the branch and how often could it result in skipping a division? Using the exception is really slow unless it happens approximately never.

Comment: im not necessarely using fpu, this is c compiled with mingw, can us sse2

Comment: fz in reality is dir.z, it is z coordinete of the normalized direction in 3d, like in raytracing, so this would be probably (if im not wrong) for the pixels in equator - but the pixelf (if im not wrong) wery rarely just aims in 0.00000 - it usualy misses the zero but sometimes it can be the zero

Comment: ps. if ya want to talk more may also go to comp.lang.c (via google groups for example) more space to talk

Comment: What if `fz` is very small - 1e-30, 1e-100? Won't that also blow up your calculation? The discontinuity at `fz=0` seems very odd.

Comment: this is part of the calculation of something like "distance" to the point when you looking at the ground. the distance is then proportional to the x/z for example 1 meter down z=1 1 meter forward leads do distance of 1, (x and z are coordinates of the normalised vector so are not indeed bot 1 length but not so important), when you have x less than z 100 times then distance x/z = 100, When looking at horizon z of directiona become to be zero and length become to infinity - it probably do not blows up the value of distance, i just got it very big

Comment: input is dir vector (xy is plane, z+1 is zenith point, z-1 is antizenith (though i reversed it temporarily so z is antizenith, wector pointing to down) - outcome of this loop is distance

Comment: so.. for each pixel i got distance, only wery unlucky cases i got exactly flat z direction of view for one pixel (as im using floats) and thus infinite distance, but it can happen ;/ and i need to check each one (i know i can do some tiles to throw out some tiles but i wonder what can be done in pure general case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but it's probably not that useful. Masking won't be useful either under the circumstances.

Exceptions are extremely slow when they happen, first a lot of microcoded complex stuff has to happen before the CPU even enters the kernel level exception handler, and then it has to hand it off to your process in a complicated and slow way too. On the other hand, they don't cost anything when they don't happen.

But a comparison and a branch don't really cost anything either, as long as the branch is predictable, which a branch that is essentially never taken *is*. Of course it costs a little throughput to make them happen at all, but they're not in the critical path .. but even if they were, the real problem here is a division in every iteration.

The throughput of that division is 1 per 14 cycles anyway (on Haswell - worse on other µarchs), unless `fz` is particularly "nice", and even then it's 1 per 8 cycles (again on Haswell). On Core2 it was more like 19 and 5, on P4 it was more like (in typical P4 fashion) one division per 71 cycles no matter what.

A well-predicted branch and a comparison just disappear into that. On my 4770K, the difference between having a comparison and branch there or not disappeared into the noise (maybe if I run it enough times I will eventually obtain a statistically significant difference, but it will be tiny), with both of them winning randomly about half the time. The code I used for this benchmark was

```
global bench
proc_frame bench
    push r11
[endprolog]
    xor ecx, ecx
    mov rax, rcx
    mov ecx, -10000000
    vxorps xmm1, xmm1
    vxorps xmm2, xmm2
    vmovapd xmm3, [rel doubleone]
_bench_loop:
    imul eax, ecx, -0xAAAAAAAB  ; distribute zeroes somewhat randomly
    shr eax, 1                  ; increase to make more zeroes
    vxorps xmm0, xmm0
    vcvtsi2sd xmm0, eax
    vcomisd xmm0, xmm1          ; #
    jz _skip                    ; #
    vdivsd xmm0, xmm3, xmm0
    vaddsd xmm2, xmm0
_skip:
    add ecx, 1
    jnz _bench_loop
    vmovapd xmm0, xmm2
    pop r11
    ret
endproc_frame
```

The other function was the same but with the two lines marked with a # commented out.

The version that eventually consistently wins when the number of zeroes is increased is the one with the branch, indicating that division by zero is significantly slower than a branch misprediction. That's *without* even using the exception mechanism to create a programmer-visible exception, it's just from the cost of the micro-coded "weird case fix-up" thing running. But you don't have that many zeroes, so,

**TL;DR** there isn't really a difference.

Comment: Interestin i got also 3 machines and tis is p4 core2 and haswell ;o very interesting answer - here is teh example of the screen  https://www.dropbox.com/s/f5bg08d1mxzht40/Zrzut%20ekranu%202014-12-06%2016.03.06.png?dl=0   i need if for each pixel though cases where z==0.0000000 are probably very rare, on the other side i take x/z mul it by some value cat to int and it with &1023 and ude it as a look up index in texture - near equator i got probably values bigger tnah MAX_INT so casting it to int already gives wrong values but incidentally it

Comment: doeas not matter much, probably if i will not get caught the exception but cast ste inf onto int then use it it will be no difference - relaying on inf would be slower than those if-cecking?

Comment: did you offed the exception on div-by-zero  or this is disabled by default? (dont think so its default) Or in your case excepton appears but no programmer handler was defined?

Comment: @user2214913 there's no programmer-visible exceptions by default, you just get +/-infinity (depending on the signs of the operands)

Comment: im using mingw32 and i got crash on div by zero as far as i remember

Comment: @user2214913 that should only happen when you're dividing integers

Comment: Interesting... if so i jus can skip if and test ...so could you say as i do not quite understood - you think it would be better to throw out if allow 1/0. to turn into inf (then cast it to int and use random value which is no harm) or better use if ?(this if is called many times, do the path of using inf is really such slow to overburdem heavy thousands of if-s?

Comment: PS I took the surprising notice just commented int and it is 10% faster (say like 6 ms instead 7 ms for lowres and 23 ms for 26 ms for hi res), this is good information, code also shorter

Comment: @user2214913 I'm not really sure what you mean anymore. By the way, if you want me to take a look at how the code can be made faster, you could ask a new question with more complete code in it.

Comment: i mean i commented out if (sorry for many mistypes) and app showed to be 15% faster

Comment: allright chec for example this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27333471/how-to-rewrite-this-code-to-sse-intrinsics