# How to rewrite this code to sse intrinsics

Tags: c++, c, x86, mingw, sse

Im new in sse intrinsics and would appreciate some hints assistance in using this 9as this is yet foggy to me)

I got such code

```
for(int k=0; k<=n-4; k+=4) 
 { 

  int xc0 = 512 + ((idx + k*iddx)>>6); 
  int yc0 = 512 + ((idy + k*iddy)>>6); 

  int xc1 = 512 + ((idx + (k+1)*iddx)>>6); 
  int yc1 = 512 + ((idy + (k+1)*iddy)>>6); 

  int xc2 = 512 + ((idx + (k+2)*iddx)>>6); 
  int yc2 = 512 + ((idy + (k+2)*iddy)>>6); 

  int xc3 = 512 + ((idx + (k+3)*iddx)>>6); 
  int yc3 = 512 + ((idy + (k+3)*iddy)>>6); 

  unsigned color0 =  working_buffer[yc0*working_buffer_size_x + xc0]; 
  unsigned color1 =  working_buffer[yc1*working_buffer_size_x + xc1]; 
  unsigned color2 =  working_buffer[yc2*working_buffer_size_x + xc2]; 
  unsigned color3 =  working_buffer[yc3*working_buffer_size_x + xc3]; 

  int adr = base_adr + k; 

  frame_bitmap[adr]  = color0; 
  frame_bitmap[adr+1]= color1; 
  frame_bitmap[adr+2]= color2; 
  frame_bitmap[adr+3]= color3; 
 }
```

all here is int/unsigned, this is critical part of the loop, not sure if integer sse would help here in speed but wonder if it would work at all? could someopne help with this?

(im using mingw32)

Comment: Could you de-obfuscate the actual access pattern to `working_buffer`? So, simply the index math. This is a bit hard to decode. I'm still not sure whether this is a "weird gather" or a pattern that can actually be worked with.

Comment: Looks like a "gather" type of operation, so you will need AVX2 at least.

Comment: working_buffer is a texture[][] of unsigned color - data there is 1024 x 1024  though sadly working_buffer low dimension is a bit larger than 1024 - though if very need i could rewrite some code to make it just unsigned texture_bitmap[1024][1024]

Comment: xc yc are index in texture (should run only on texture area from 0 to 1023 , 0 to 1023 ) This is unwinded loop becouse unwinding it makes it faster even in scalar code; i do not expect noticable speedup in sse but would like to get accustomed how to do such things and its foggy to me (esp integer intrisinc)

Comment: the patter itself is for given pixel i, j, transform to texture coordinate reading the texture color and assign to frame_bitmap - though whole algorithm is divided by tiles (12x12) and this is x-line in tile (n is 12 right now, this is for 4 pixels at once)

Comment: What are the values of *idx, iddx, idy, iddy, working_buffer_size_x, base_adr*?

Comment: xc0 and 7 others spans area [0..1023][0..1023], base adr is memory pointer, working_buffer_x is about 1040

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My sse is a bit rusty, but what you should do is:

```
xmm0: [k, k+1, k+2, k+3] //xc0, xc1,....
xmm1: [k, k+1, k+2, k+3] //yc0, yc1,....
//initialize before the loop
xmm2: [512, 512, 512, 512]
xmm3: [idx, idx, idx, idx]
xmm4: [iddx, iddx, iddx, iddx]
xmm5: [idy, idy, idy, idy]
xmm6: [iddy, iddy, iddy, iddy]
xmm7: [working_buffer_size_x, working_buffer_size_x, working_buffer_size_x, working_buffer_size_x]
```

Calculations:

```
xmm0 * xmm4
xmm0 + xmm3
xmm0 >> 6
xmm0 + xmm2

xmm0: [xc0, xc1, xc2, xc3]
///////////////////////////////

xmm1 * xmm6
xmm1 + xmm5
xmm1 >> 6
xmm1 + xmm2

xmm1: [yc0, yc1, yc2, yc3]

xmm1 * xmm7
xmm1 + xmm0
```

Now `xmm1` is:

```
xmm1: [yc0*working_buffer_size_x + xc0, yc1*working_buffer_size_x + xc1, yc2*working_buffer_size_x + xc2, yc3*working_buffer_size_x + xc3]
```

You are reading and writing memory in each loop (working_buffer, frame_bitmap arrays), operations that are way too slower than the calculations itself, so the speed improvement won't be as much as you expected to be.

**EDIT**

You need *working_buffer and frame_bitmap* arrays to be aligned and *SSE4.1*:

```
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <smmintrin.h> //SSE4.1

int a[4] __attribute__((aligned(16)));
__m128i xmm0, xmm1, xmm2, xmm3, xmm4, xmm5, xmm6, xmm7;

xmm2 = _mm_set1_epi32(512);
xmm3 = _mm_set1_epi32(idx);
xmm4 = _mm_set1_epi32(iddx);
xmm5 = _mm_set1_epi32(idy);
xmm6 = _mm_set1_epi32(iddy);
xmm7 = _mm_set1_epi32(working_buffer_size_x);

for(k = 0; k <= n - 4; k +=4){
    xmm0 = _mm_set_epi32(k + 3, k + 2, k + 1, k);
    xmm1 = _mm_set_epi32(k + 3, k + 2, k + 1, k);

    //xmm0 * xmm4
    xmm0 = _mm_mullo_epi32(xmm0, xmm4);

    //xmm0 + xmm3
    xmm0 = _mm_add_epi32(xmm0, xmm3);

    //xmm0 >> 6
    xmm0 = _mm_srai_epi32(xmm0, 6);

    //xmm0 + xmm2
    xmm0 = _mm_add_epi32(xmm0, xmm2);



    //xmm1 * xmm6
    xmm1 = _mm_mullo_epi32(xmm1, xmm6);

    //xmm1 + xmm5
    xmm1 = _mm_add_epi32(xmm1, xmm5);

    //xmm1 >> 6
    xmm1 = _mm_srai_epi32(xmm1, 6);

    //xmm1 + xmm2
    xmm1 = _mm_add_epi32(xmm1, xmm2);


    //xmm1 * xmm7
    xmm1 = _mm_mullo_epi32(xmm1, xmm7);
    //xmm1 + xmm0
    xmm1 = _mm_add_epi32(xmm1, xmm0);


    //a[0] = yc0*working_buffer_size_x + xc0
    //a[1] = yc1*working_buffer_size_x + xc1
    //a[2] = yc2*working_buffer_size_x + xc2
    //a[3] = yc3*working_buffer_size_x + xc3
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i *)&a[0], xmm1);

    unsigned color0 =  working_buffer[ a[0] ]; 
    unsigned color1 =  working_buffer[ a[1] ]; 
    unsigned color2 =  working_buffer[ a[2] ]; 
    unsigned color3 =  working_buffer[ a[3] ]; 

    int adr = base_adr + k; 

    frame_bitmap[adr]  = color0; 
    frame_bitmap[adr+1]= color1; 
    frame_bitmap[adr+2]= color2; 
    frame_bitmap[adr+3]= color3; 
}
```

You can optimize it even more by avoiding the `_mm_store_si128((__m128i *)&a[0], xmm1);` or the `int adr = base_adr + k;` using assembly with direct manipulation of memory.

Comment: well, i know speed improvements may be not large here (if any, more would be in the case of divisions or sqrt)  but anywaj i wopuld like to test it if it all in all works

Comment: ps this is a part of work maybe someone could continue it a bit further ? the mnemonics i know are like  __m128 a128   = _mm_load_ps(a);  __m128 b128   = _mm_load_ps(b);  __m128 out128 = _mm_div_ps(a128, b128);  _mm_store_ps(out, out128);

Comment: @user2214913 As I said, i did write intrinsics many months ago so I dont remember them. But your example is very easy. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: great thanx - i will ned some time to check it